# Слетел BIOS(UEFI) после установки ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bios, uefi

После чистой установки ubuntu на ноутбук acer swift sf314-52 Перестал открываться биос.
В интернете говорят мол "boot-repair" помогаетно вот как мне воспользоваться им когда я не могу выставить приоритет загрузки для liveusb
А варианты с замыканием контактов и изьятием батарейки биоса не подходят так как попытка разобрать ноутбук не удалась

(Сама убунту запускаеться отлично)